# What's wrong with my Python code? An example in Head First Python

Tags: python, class

It says

```
    sarah = Athlete('Sarah Sweeney', '2002-6-17', ['2:58', '2.58', '1.56'])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

What's wrong? Thank you. It is the example in Head First Python

```
class Athlete:
    def _init_(self, a_name, a_dob=None, a_times=[]):
        self.name = a_name
        self.dob = a_dob
        self.times = a_times

sarah = Athlete('Sarah Sweeney', '2002-6-17', ['2:58', '2.58', '1.56'])
```

Comment: Change `_init_` to `__init__`

Comment: You *probably* do **not** want to use a mutable list value `[]` for a default, see ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: I hope you've read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you don't overload magic `__init__` method of the `object` class. Instead of that you define a new method called `_init_` which has no special meaning to Python (special methods in Python should be surrounded with double underscores).

As far as your class does not overload `__init__`, a default one (inherited from `object`) gets called every time you instantiate the class. And that default one takes no arguments.

See also: [Special (magic) methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090620/special-magic-methods-in-python), [Where is the Python documentation for the special methods? (__init__, __new__, __len__, ...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418825/python-classes-special-methods)

Answer (score 3):

You've misspelt `__init__` (note the *double* underscores at the start and the end).